# can not call $wpdb in functions.php in wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I was trying to query the database in my theme's functions.php, but it shows

> Fatal error:  Call to a member function get_results() on a non-object in .../functions.php

I was wondering what did I do wrong. Any help will be appreciate. Thanks.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

try `global $wpdb;` before your query

Comment: to check it, you can `var_dump( $wpdb );`